# Packaging with pyinstaller: PyQt4 module not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hi everyone and thanks for reading. I'm packaging my python code in a single file using pyinstaller, but when I run my packaged file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 409, in importHook
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
```

I don't know what this error is telling me, especially since there is no dir name pyinstaller-2.0 on my desktop and I did not use PyQt4 at all.

Imported modules: `Tkinter, tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox, multiprocessing, os, sys, time, numpy, scipy.weave, pywt, matplotlib.pyplot`

I think the problem is related to `multiprocessing`, since I did not experience this error before. I used [this recipe](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/Multiprocessing) to implement the `multiprocessing` module correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using `PyQt` then the only way to import the modules with PyInstaller is to use

```
 from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

rather than

```
 import PyQt4.QtCore, PyQt4.QtGui
```

which your error implies. However, you say that you're not using `PyQt`.

`PyQt` is an optional dependency of `matplotlib` so there is a chance that PyInstaller is checking the `matplotlib` module and consequently including `PyQt`.

I would suggest excluding the `PyQt` module from the build; in your `.spec` file, search out the line for the `Analysis` class - something like

```
Analysis( ..., excludes=['PyQt4', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui'])
```

and edit the `excludes` keyword arg as suggested above.